# How to ready empty value xml tag in gwt client side

Tags: gwt

In GWT client side, when I am reading empty tag,
it throws null pointer exception. If I use an `if` condition on that particular parsing tag it also results in a null pointer exception. So kindly give me the solution.

My coding is:

```
if (list.getElementsByTagName("insertId").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() != null &&
    !list.getElementsByTagName("insertId").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
    shipDetails.nmFormNo.setValue(Double.valueOf(
        list.getElementsByTagName("insertId").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()));
}
```

And my particular tag is:

```
      <insertId></insertId>
```

Answer (score 0):

So its throwing null pointer even before checking your  `null condition`

possibilities are

```
1)list.getElementsByTagName("insertId").item(0) throwing null
2)list.getElementsByTagName("insertId").item(0).getFirstChild () throwing null
```

Comment: sorry bro, I made mistake.your answer is only correct. no.2.list.getElementsByTagName("insertId").item(0).getFirstChild ()